# Print all values, options, checked checkbox & radio in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a question.
How to print/display in console all inputs values, selected options, checked checkbox & radio from form on submit?

searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
      var inputType = $(this).attr("type");
      var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      if (inputType === "checkbox" || inputType === "radio") {
        inputValue = $(this).is(":checked") ? "Yes" : "No";
      }
      console.log(inputName + ": " + inputValue);
    });
  });
});
```

This will "detect" all `:input`  elements and will write out different information based on the type,name and value

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
      var inputType = $(this).attr("type");
      var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      if (inputType === "checkbox" || inputType === "radio") {
        inputValue = $(this).is(":checked") ? "Yes" : "No";
      }
      console.log(inputName + ": " + inputValue);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

  <label for="age">Age:</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" name="age"><br><br>

  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
  <select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <label for="newsletter">Subscribe to newsletter:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" value="yes"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's it, thank you:) I forgot about the textarea but I can handle it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're submitting the form via AJAX, and that your form is not causing the page to reload, one way of doing it (apart from what @CarstenLøvboAndersen suggests) could be:

```
$("<your_form_identifier>").on("submit",function() {
    var ser = $(this).serialize();
    var serArr = $(this).serializeArray();

    console.log(ser);
    console.log(serArr);
});
```

where `<your_form_identifier>` is the way you... Well, identify the form (ID, class, some other selector).

If you don't care about the actual type of the element, and you don't want that shown in the console, this suggestion will log:

- `$(this).serialize()` - a string, in the form of `name=value&name2=value2...` for all of the form elements which are submitted (checked checkboxes, checked radiobuttons, etc)
- `$(this).serializeArray()` - similar as the first, but as an array, instead of a string

If you're not using AJAX to submit your form, and are in fact reloading the page, then this suggestion (and the one by @CarstenLøvboAndersen) won't enable you to see what is being submitted, unless you interrupt the submission with something like `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: thx, great idea but how to display only those that have been completed or checked? not empty;

Comment: @DeusVictim Apologies for the late reply. If you go with `serializeArray`, you can loop through that array, and remove the empty / unfilled form elements. For example, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ha8uxrf3/). If you don't want to loop through the array, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ha8uxrf3/1/)